# initial value of reference to non-const must be lvalue for a string passed as parameter

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error when I pass string s as parameter to the function interleave. It tells me the initial value of reference to a non-const must be an lvalue. How do I rectify this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void interleave(string s1, string s2, string s, int i, int j, vector<string> &ans) {
    if (i == s1.length() && j == s2.length()) {
        ans.push_back("" + s);
    }

    if (i != s1.length()) {
            interleave(s1, s2, s, i + 1, j, s + s1.at(i));
    }

    if (j != s2.length()) {
            interleave(s1, s2, s, i, j + 1, s + s2.at(j));
    }
}


int main() {
    string s1, s2;
    cin >> s1 >> s2;
    vector<string> ans;
    string s;
    interleave(s1, s2, s, 0, 0, ans);


}
```

Comment: Your 6th parameter of `interleave()` is of type `std::vector<std::string>&`. You apply `s + s1.at(i)` which results in type `std::string`. (The same for `s + s2.at(i)`.) You cannot pass an argument of type `std::string` where `std::vector<std::string>&` is required. Something went wrong in your algorithm design. Compiler complaints regarding this: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6547ea5d91434c42) (I removed `-Wall -pedantic` from compiler arguments to focus on your actual issue.)

Comment: It would really help if you can describe in English what your code is supposed to accomplish.  Also, `"" + s` is the same as `s`.

Comment: U don't put `#include<string>` in the first of the code besides U R trying to pass `std::string` `value` instedade of `std::vector<std::string>&`